# Mysql query or Eloquent to calculate total based on items and discount on order and item level

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-optimization, laravel-5

I have orders and Order_Items table. I need to calculate the total with inc and ex VAT after applying line discount and order discount. How to calculate the final price inc and ex vat? I am using Laravel and using relationships it gets really slow once I have about 20k orders and  70k order_items.

Orders

- id(PK)
- user_id
- register_id
- sale_time
- has_discount
- discount_is_percentage
- discount_amount

Order_Items

- id(PK)
- order_id(FK)
- has_discount
- discount_is_percentage
- discount_amount
- price
- quantity
- vat_rate

First I calculate the price ex and inc vat on the item level applying the discount. Then add them to get the sales total. calculate the order discount by applying the order discount on the total. Apply the discount to the items to calculate item price after discount. Then adding the item amounts to get the order total. I do that all in the Laravel model and collection and all works fine if there are few thousands entries but as the list grows, it takes longer and longer time.

Should I store the calculated values directly at the orders table? Or how else can I optimize this query. I need to report by up to a year and the the count can go few millions in a year for a given client.

Also I will be doing report grouped by different columns(user_id, register_id) and by day and hour. So Eloquent collection works for now but really slow.

I am using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to add `accessors` to your `Order` model.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
// comment it out if you don't need it in your model
protected $appends = ['total'];

public function getTotalAttribute()
{
    $items = $this->items();
    // do the needed calculations

    return $result;
}
```

***EDIT***

Since the main problem is the performance, you could instead use a `mutator` and `queue` the `calculate / save process`. So you would calculate the totals on `order` save / change and put the result into the `orders` table.

Comment: I have that already, that's how I am getting the final total but it's slow for larger datasets. I am also eager loading the relationship and the query count is 4 with 700ms when I try with Postman. But the response time is around 30 seconds.